# ajax request getting HTTP status code 403

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I already create POST method in Spring and I want consume with AJAX POST but I found an error.

My code is:

#### Controller Spring:

```
@PostMapping(value={"/tesinsert"}, consumes={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody KasusEntity user) throws Exception {
    Map result = new HashMap();
    userService.insertTabel(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

#### Javascript:

```
var data = {
        "kodekasus":5,
        "nama":"baru",
        "isdelete":1,
        "createdby":"hahaa",
        "createddate":null,
        "updatedby":"hihii",
        "updateddate":null
};

    var url = "http://localhost:8089/SpringNew/tesinsert";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data), 
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log('sukses: '+data); 
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('gagal: '+error);
        }
        ,
        headers: {
            Accept : "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            }
    });
```

- How can I solve this problem?
- How to finding error source? in javascript or spring?

Comment: If you are using Spring Security you need to pass `csrfToken` in the `setRequestHeader`. Are you using Spring Security??

Comment: I not use spring security.. can you give me link for tutorial csrfToken? thank you

Comment: so, must I disabled csrfToken?

Comment: If you are not using spring security, you don't need to provide the csrfToken.

Comment: So, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP status code 403 means [access forbidded or denied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)**

So May be your application is not permitted to request to the endpoint with the credential you are trying.

May be some security things blocks your request. You have find that, it should be in **Spring (i mean in your application server)**